# Amadeus : Travel Build Request for Flight response error " 17|Session|No agreement on destination"

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, amadeus

I have been having issues with Amadues Web SOAP request.I tried creating a reservation for the flight, i keep getting following error.

"17|session|No agreement on destination"

Here is my code(C# .NET Core 3.1):

```
public async Task<Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchResponse> SearchFlight(Session session,
            Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch searchData)
        {
            MethodInfo method = typeof(XmlSerializer).GetMethod("set_Mode", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            method.Invoke(null, new object[] { 1 });

            var result = await _client.Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearchAsync(session, searchData);
            return result ;
        }
```

Exception:

```
System.AggregateException: 'Event ServiceChannelBeginCallStart (with ID 704) has the same task/opcode pair as event ServiceChannelCallStart (with ID 703). 17|Session|No agreement on destination
```

Stack Trace:

```
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Comment: Amadeus web services (SOAP only) currently does not work with .NET Core, you need to use native .NET

Comment: But some tutorial sites says, we can add SOAP WSDL via "Add Connected Services"  in .NET Core

Comment: Yeah, I tried that as that was my understanding. However, I started getting header errors and then Amadeus advised that .NET Core does not work with their SOAP web services, after which, I did not ask for further information, I had a deadline to meet! You could always ask your contact point at Amadeus for more information as to why it does not work